# Is it possible to restart a supermicro kvm with ipmitool? (the kvm not the server)

Tags: linux, freebsd, ipmi, supermicro, ipmitool

The KVM on my supermicro motherboard seems to have crashed or is otherwise not answering network requests on it's assigned IP address. I need to try to restart the KVM (not the server). Is this possible to do with the `ipmitool` utility from inside the host operating system? Or do I have to restart the entire machine?

I'd like to avoid restarting the entire machine if possible. I've used `ipmitool` in the past to reset the admin password on the KVM, but I can't seem to find how to restart the KVM. It only seems to have options to restart the host OS.

The host is running FreeBSD but it should be the same `ipmitool` as is available in Linux, so I've tagged it as both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following ipmitool command:

```
ipmitool mc reset cold
```